# Question about the probability $X_1 < X_2$ given $X_2 < X_3$ for IID geometric random variables X?

Tags: probability

Consider three independent random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3$. For $i = 1, 2, 3$, $X_i$
is a geometric
random variable with parameter p. Find the probability of the event $(X_1 < X_2)$ conditioned
on the event $(X_2 < X_3)$.

I just say that $$P(X_1<X_2|X_2<X_3) = P(X_1<X_2, X_2<X_3)/P(X_2<X_3) = P(X_1<X_2<X_3)/P(X_2<X_3) = (1/3!)/(1/2)$$

What's wrong with this argument? Probability that you get a sequence $X1<X2<X3$ is simply 1/3! (the permutation), similar argument with the denominator.

Comment: Your symmetry argument excludes cases such as $X_1=X_2 < X_3$, for example.

Comment: @angryavian Ah I see. So this works with continuous random variables right? Also, is this the only problem?

Comment: @Goldname The same problem appeared in denominator. Yes, this argument works with continuous random variables only.